# trimming and removing adapter from sequences in biopython

Tags: python, biopython

I got this question that I am unable to solve:
A user has an input DNA.txt file which consists of 5 sequences. Each sequences starts with the same 14 base pair fragment - a sequencing adapter that should have been removed. Write a program that will
(a) trim this adapter and write the cleaned sequences to a new file and
(b) print the length of each sequence

I am actually new in biopython. i thought of using strip() from Seq modules, but i don't think it will work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

think I got it, not using biopython though:

```
import io

file =io.StringIO('AAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTT\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTT\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTT\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTT\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTT\n')

print('read file :')    
for i in file.readlines():
    print(i.strip(),'\n')
file.seek(0)

newfile =io.StringIO()
for i in file.readlines():
    i = i.lstrip('AAAAAAAAAAAAAA')
    #print(i)
    newfile.write(i)
newfile.seek(0)

print('read newfile :')    
for i in newfile.readlines():
    print(i.strip() + ' lenght : ', len(i),'\n')
```

output:

```
read file :
AAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTT 

AAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTT 

AAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTT 

AAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTT 

AAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTT 

read newfile :
TTTTT lenght :  6 

TTTTT lenght :  6 

TTTT lenght :  5 

TTTTT lenght :  6 

TTTTT lenght :  6
```

If you go for `biopython` route you should be able to use `lstrip` the same way on `Seq` object as per the manual:  https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.Seq.html#Bio.Seq.Seq.lstrip :

> lstrip(self, chars=None)

> Return a new Seq object with leading (left) end stripped.

> This behaves like the python string method of the same name.

> Optional argument chars defines which characters to remove. If omitted or None (default) then as for the python string method, this defaults to removing any white space.

> e.g. print(my_seq.lstrip(“-“))

> See also the strip and rstrip methods.

**USING Biopython:**

```
from Bio import SeqIO

import io

file =io.StringIO('>1\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTT\n>2\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTT\n>3\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTT\n>4\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTT\n>5\nAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTT\n')




print('read file :')    


for i in SeqIO.parse(file, 'fasta'):
    print(i.seq,'\n')
file.seek(0)

newfile =io.StringIO()

sequences = []

for i in SeqIO.parse(file, 'fasta'):
    i.seq = i.seq.lstrip('AAAAAAAAAAAAAA')
    
    sequences.append(i)
    
    
# print('...', sequences)

SeqIO.write(sequences, newfile, 'fasta')

newfile.seek(0)

for i in SeqIO.parse(newfile, 'fasta'):
    # print(i,'\n')
    print(i.seq, 'lenght :', len(i.seq),'\n')
newfile.seek(0)
```

output:

```
read file :
AAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTT 

AAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTT 

AAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTT 

AAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTT 

AAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTT 

TTTTT lenght : 5 

TTTTT lenght : 5 

TTTT lenght : 4 

TTTTT lenght : 5 

TTTTT lenght : 5
```

uncommenting `# print(i,'\n')` in the last loop, that parse

the `newfile` will output:

```
............

ID: 4
Name: 4
Description: 4
Number of features: 0
Seq('TTTTT') 

......
```

that is the `__str__` value of  `SeqRecord` object, while its

`__repr__` obtained with `print(repr(i))` would be:

`SeqRecord(seq=Seq('TTTTT'), id='4', name='4', description='4', dbxrefs=[])`

everything is explained: https://biopython.org/docs/1.78/api/Bio.SeqRecord.html

be sure to check the version of biopython you are using:

```
import Bio
print('version :', Bio.__version__)
```